# How to memorize previous payload in reactive extensions observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an IObservable boolObservable, the publisher acts like switch. There is also the variable currentItem with some value and the defaultItem containing pre-defined immutable value. Whenever 'true' is published, currentItem's value should be memorized, and currentItem should be set to defaultItem. When 'false' is published, currentItem's value should be changed to the previous one.
The easiest way to achieve this is to have the local variable.

```cs
IObservable<bool> boolObservable;
string currentItem;
string defaultItem;

string local = null;
boolObservable.Subscribe(x =>
  {
    if (x) {
      local = currentItem;
      currentItem = defaultItem;
    }
    else
      currentItem = local;
  });
```

The problems begin when I have to repeat this several times and name local variable used for storage each time differentely. Is there a way to use Rx operators to "remember" not only the latest payload, but also the one before it?

**UPD:** @ibebbs' answer below is absolutely correct, `Scan` operator provides the necessary behavior:

```cs
var switchSource = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
string currentItem = "FromDb";
string defaultItem = "Default";

switchSource
    .Skip(1)
    .Scan(string.Empty, (local, b) =>
    {
        if (b)
        {
            local = currentItem;
            currentItem = defaultItem;
        }
        else
            currentItem = local;

        return local;
    })
    .Subscribe();

Console.WriteLine($"Initial value: {currentItem}"); // FromDb
switchSource.OnNext(true);
Console.WriteLine($"Default value: {currentItem}"); // Default
switchSource.OnNext(false);
Console.WriteLine($"Initial value again: {currentItem}"); // FromDb
currentItem = "UserChanged";
Console.WriteLine($"UserChanged value: {currentItem}"); // UserChanged
switchSource.OnNext(true);
Console.WriteLine($"Default value: {currentItem}"); // Default
switchSource.OnNext(false);
Console.WriteLine($"UserChanged value again: {currentItem}"); // UserChanged
```

Comment: Where is the value for `currentItem` initially coming from? Is it an observable source as well? How should the `currentItem` change (or not change) when the "switch" is set to use the default value? The solution might be a simple `CombineLatest()`, but it's difficult to tell. Please add some kind of diagram on how/when which value should be set where/when and how these values change over time.

Comment: @Progman `currentItem`  is initially coming from the database. It can be also changed by the user when `boolObservable`'s source BehaviorSubject<bool> value is set to false. It can not be changed otherwise. It is actually treated as a simple mutable property, but can be converted to IObservable<string> as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scan](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#Scan) to thread state through an observable sequence. For example:

```cs
public static IObservable<string> EitherItemOrDefault(IObservable<bool> switchSource, IObservable<string> itemSource, string defaultValue)
{
    return switchSource
        .WithLatestFrom(itemSource.StartWith(string.Empty), (switchValue, itemValue) => (Switch: switchValue, Item: itemValue))
        .Scan(
            (Current: string.Empty, Local: string.Empty),
            (seed, tuple) => tuple.Switch 
                            ? (Current: defaultValue, Local: tuple.Item) 
                            : (Current: seed.Local, Local: seed.Local))
        .Select(tuple => tuple.Current);
}
```

This takes an `IObservable<bool>` as your "switches" and an `IObservable<string>` as the items (`currentItem` in your example) and returns an `IObservable<string>` which will contain the `defaultValue` when `switchSource` emits a `False` and the last `currentItem` value when the `switchSource` emits a `True`.

Note: I may have got `current` and `local` backwards. It's late and your example neatly illustrates why global state should be avoided... it's just so tricky to reason about.

Comment: Thanks, `Scan` operator was exactly what I was looking for.